# Overwriting zip file in expression with user variable in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl

I want to overwrite a zip file in a folder but when i tried the below expression, it is giving an error as:

> The expression is not valid and could not be parsed. it might contain invalid elements.

Expression:

```
@[User::Command_Syntax] = " /c copy  " + "\"" + @[User::Output_File_Path_Var] + substring(@[User::Output_Zip_Name_Var], 1, len(@[User::Output_Zip_Name_Var]) - 4) +  REPLACE(right(@[User::Output_Zip_Name_Var], 4) , ".zip", "") +  ".zip"  + "\"" + " " + "\"" + @[User::Archive_File_Path_Var] + substring(@[User::Output_Zip_Name_Var], 1, len(@[User::Output_Zip_Name_Var]) - 4) +  REPLACE(right(@[User::Output_Zip_Name_Var], 4) , ".zip", "") +  ".zip" + "\""
```

Can any one please let me know why i'm getting error. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I use a tool, which is outside of Visual Studio, which helps troubleshoot expression building. The tool information is here: [SQLIS | SSIS Expression Editor & Tester](http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/ssis-expression-editor-tool.aspx) and the github is here: [SSIS Expression GitHub](https://github.com/sqlgreen/SSIS-Expression-Editor)

That being said, I copy/pasted your expression above into the editor, added in the @ user variables with made-up values in the "Add Variable" ability of the tool, and I get this as my output when evaluating.

[image]

So it does seem to evaluate for me, could you verify your user variables are spelled correctly and they are the correct type (string)?

You could also verify the variable assignments during debugging. Here is a good article on how to debug, if needed: [Debugging Control Flow in SSIS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4543/debugging-control-flow-in-sql-server-integration-services--part-1/)